# How to assign a specific color to NA in an image plot

Tags: r

I am using the `image` command to plot a matrix, the matrix contains some `NA` values. I am using `image` like

```
image(figData, zlim = zRange, col = colors, useRaster=TRUE)
```

`zRange` is smaller than the actual range of the `figData`. I am using the top colormap in the following group, which is compatible with red-green color perception deficiencies:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/31761/6/thumbnail_184481.jpg

I want to select a specific color for `NA` values in `figData` that is outside `colors` (for example, `gray`). `NA` values are being mapped now to the last element of `colors` (`white`) and therefore I can't distinguish them from out of range values.

Ideally I would like a solution that works no matter which color palette I am using.

I want something similar to the `na.color` option in `heatmap.2`, how can I do it? I am willing to modify the `image` source code to accomplish this, but `image` seems to call the `rasterImage` function whose source code I can't find.

---

After accepting Jealie's answer I am including here the code to account differently for values below and above the range:

```
image.nan <- function(z,  zlim, col, na.color='gray', outside.below.color='black', outside.above.color='white',...)
{
  zstep <- (zlim[2] - zlim[1]) / length(col); # step in the color palette
  newz.below.outside <- zlim[1] - zstep # new z for values below zlim
  newz.above.outside <- zlim[2] + zstep # new z for values above zlim
  newz.na <- zlim[2] + 2 * zstep # new z for NA

  z[which(z<zlim[1])] <- newz.below.outside # we affect newz.below.outside
  z[which(z>zlim[2])] <- newz.above.outside # we affect newz.above.outside
  z[which(is.na(z>zlim[2]))] <- newz.na # same for newz.na

  zlim[1] <- zlim[1] - zstep # extend lower limit to include below value
  zlim[2] <- zlim[2] + 2 * zstep # extend top limit to include the two new values above and na

  col <- c(outside.below.color, col, outside.above.color, na.color) # we construct the new color range by including: na.color and na.outside

  image(z=z,  zlim=zlim, col=col, ...) # we finally call image(...)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small correction: values outside are not being mapped to the last element of `col`, but they are instead not being plotted at all (and no color looks white..).

Otherwise, to answer your question, the simplest way is to write a wrapper around `image`, with two new arguments: `na.color` and `outside.color`. Here is my suggestion, which defaults to `gray` for NA values and `white` for values outside `zlim`:

```
my.image <- function(figData,  zlim, col, na.color='gray', outside.color='white', ...)
{
  newz.na <- zlim[2]+(zlim[2]-zlim[1])/length(col) # new z for NA
  newz.outside <- zlim[2]+2*(zlim[2]-zlim[1])/length(col) # new z for values outside zlim

  figData$z[which(is.na(figData$z>zlim[2]))] <- newz.na # we affect newz.outside
  figData$z[which(figData$z<zlim[1] | figData$z>zlim[2])] <- newz.outside # same for newz.na


  zlim[2] <- zlim[2]+2*(zlim[2]-zlim[1])/length(col) # we finally extend the z limits to include the two new values 

  col <- c(col, na.color, outside.color) # we construct the new color range by including: na.color and outside.color

  image(figData,  zlim=zlim, col=col, ...) # we finally call image(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, solution and code example. Now I understand why some areas that I expected to be black where actually white surrounded by a line that I suppose is the transition from white color to transparent. To avoid this I created a new version of your code including the distinction between below and above the limits. I am including it at the end of my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

Because the color intervals are defined like `(*bottom*, *top*]`, values in z that are equal to zlim[1] will be colored with outside.below.color (because the range of outside.below.color is `( *zlim[1] - zstep* , *zlim[1]* ]` ).

The following version fixes this bug:

```
image.nan.better <- function(z,  zlim, col, na.color='gray', outside.below.color='black', outside.above.color='white',...)
{
      zstep <- (zlim[2] - zlim[1]) / length(col); # step in the color palette
      newz.below.outside <- zlim[1] - 2 * zstep # new z for values below zlim
      newz.above.outside <- zlim[2] + zstep # new z for values above zlim
      newz.na <- zlim[2] + 2 * zstep # new z for NA

      z[which(z<zlim[1])] <- newz.below.outside # we affect newz.below.outside
      z[which(z>zlim[2])] <- newz.above.outside # we affect newz.above.outside
      z[which(is.na(z>zlim[2]))] <- newz.na # same for newz.na

      zlim[1] <- zlim[1] - 2 * zstep # extend lower limit to include below value
      zlim[2] <- zlim[2] + 2 * zstep # extend top limit to include the two new values above and na

      col <- c(outside.below.color, col[1], col, outside.above.color, na.color) #correct by including col[1] at bottom of range

      image(z=z,  zlim=zlim, col=col, ...) # we finally call image(...)
}
```

compare:

```
f = matrix(abs(rnorm(300)),nrow=50)
f[which(f>1)]=1

f[44,4] = 0
f[41,4] = NA
f[42,4] = NA
f[43,4] = NA
f[44,3] = -1
f[44,5] = 2

image(as.matrix(f),col=c('green3','green2','blue1','blue3'),zlim=c(0,1))

image.nan(as.matrix(f),col=c('green3','green2','blue1','blue3'),zlim=c(0,1),outside.below.color='red',outside.above.color='brown',na.color='yellow')

image.nan.better(as.matrix(f),col=c('green3','green2','blue1','blue3'),zlim=c(0,1),outside.below.color='red',outside.above.color='brown',na.color='yellow')
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Small tweak to function prototype to make it easier to use: image.nan.better <- function(mat,  zlim=range(mat,na.rm=T), col=heat.colors(100), na.color='gray', outside.below.color='black', outside.above.color='white',...){

Answer (score 1):

Solution used by `heatmap.2` seems to be bit simpler than the one given in the previous answers. First plot the actual data, then plot just `NA`s using your `na.color`.

```
na.color <- "grey"
image(figData, zlim = zRange, col = colors, useRaster=TRUE)
if (any(is.na(figData))) {
    mmat <- ifelse(is.na(figData), 1, NA)
    image(mmat, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = na.color, useRaster=TRUE, add = TRUE)
  }
```